# Trouble with Xdebug remote_connect_back MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, macos-catalina

Let me say first and foremost, I am not trying to INSTALL Xdebug locally on my Mac and can not run the application on my Mac.  I also can not downgrade my OS below Catalina so let's just not discuss those options please...

I got a new Macbook Pro running MacOS Catalina (10.15.7) and can not get Xdebug working to save my life. The PHP application runs on a SHARED development server hosted on Amazon.  Seeing as how the environment is shared among several developers, we use Xdebug via `remote_connect_back` setting.

With my old Macbook Pro running High Sierra (10.13.3), it connects just fine and step debugging has been working for years. The result is the same with all of my co-workers: those on Mojave and below have no issue and Xdebug works wonderfully.  All of us with Catalina and higher can not get Xdebug to connect to our machines from the shared dev server.  We are all running PhpStorm 2020.3, and use the Chrome Xdebug helper plugin (with "phpstorm" set as the IDE key).

I have set up this configuration at least 2 dozen times (and wrote the company guide for setting up the dev environments including Xdebug), so it's a bit embarrassing that it won't work on newer Macbooks.

The computer I am currently testing has the firewall disabled, no internet security, clean install as of yesterday. Also tried with gatekeeper disabled, rootless protection disabled and Allow Remote connections from ANYONE.  All to no avail.  On my previous laptop, I can ssh into the dev server, and open a telnet session on port 9000 to my local laptop and it works fine.  On the NEW computer, if I attempt a telnet session on port 9000 it just times out.

What is interesting is if I turn OFF listening for Xdebug connections in PhpStorm and run the telnet command again, I IMMEDIATELY get a connection refused message.  So I KNOW I am getting the right machine, it's almost as if Apple implemented some security through obscurity logic between Mojave and Catalina.

It's also worth noting that one co-worker is running Catalina, but version 10.15.2 and his connects just fine and he is refusing to update (reasonably so).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit/Update: I have tried both xdebug 2.7.2 via remote connect back on port 9000 and 3.02 via discover remote host on port 9003.

Second Edit/Update: If I open a reverse ssh tunnel on my laptop (ssh -N -R 9003:127.0.0.1:9003 dev_server_host) I can get Xdebug to work. However this solution isn't practical on a SHARED dev server as if more than one person does this we get cross talk.  Just noting it to help with troubleshooting.

Third Edit/Update: This issue is still unresolved so I would love to find a solution at some point, but I have moved on by working with coworkers to get it running locally on docker.  On docker we have no issue getting xdebug to connect. Our unit tests run a bit slower in docker, whether the code is mounted via a volume or not, but that is another topic for another day.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so cannot properly help here. But a few comments anyway. 1) If you use different port number for Xdebug (e.g. `9003` that Xdebug v3 uses by default) -- will it make any difference in behaviour? Obviously, you would need to change that in php.ini and PhpStorm (make sure it was not listening for connections at that stage; if it did -- turn off and on again). 2) Just in case: what process is actually listen on your machine on that port -- is that just PhpStorm? `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` and check from there

Comment: 3) Will telnet connect if you try that from another Mac in your office? When no external firewall/router is involved at all; only LAN. 4) I actually think that all those #1-#3 will be good and it's an actual MacOS config thingy. Could that be that the OS checks some stuff (app signature / manifest file -- forget the file name used on Mac) that was modified after installation, e.g. by using in-place patch upgrade route? Try on one of the machines: uninstall PhpStorm (but keep the settings intact) and then just install it again from full installer.

Comment: 5) What about LittleSnitch (if you have it)? I've seen a ticket or some forum thread recently where that app was causing some network related functionality issues with PhpStorm...

Comment: I have tried xdebug 2.x on port 9000 and xdebug 3.x on port 9003 and updated phpstorm settings accordingly.  I can see phpstorm listening with sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN.

I will try a telnet from laptop to laptop for posterity.  If I telnet FROM my laptop back to itself (127.0.0.1) it connects just fine.

I don't have little snitch installed, but may install it just for debugging purposes to see if I even get alerted of an incoming connection etc.

Comment: @MikeTeall https://www.grzegorowski.com/docker-with-xdebug-and-vdebug says that xdebug.remote_connect_back is not supported in Docker for Mac. I did not have the time to check other sources. If I have some time I will do it later. However, can that be the cause of your issue?

Comment: @saulotoledo I was discussing a shared remote development web server on AWS.  I eventually gave up on trying to troubleshoot this issue and proceeded to dockerize our web application so people COULD run it locally.  Xdebug has no problem connecting with the local docker container, I am not using remote connect back as there is no need since I am the only one connecting to it.